# add likes to post (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I have a **blog** built with **laravel**.
and I want to **add likes** to my **posts**.
so I created a `Like` model with a `likes` table.

this is what i have done in my `Like` *model*

```
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

in my *Post* and *User* models

```
    public function likes(){
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }
```

and my migration file for *likes* table

```
        Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->boolean('value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I want to set the values in my controller on this way!

```
public function liker($postID, $userID, $value){
        $like = new Like([
            'post_id' => $postID,
            'user_id' => $userID,
            'value' => $value
        ]);
        $like->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

but the view return 419 error page. (Page Expired)

and also no changes (no row) adds to my database(likes table)!
can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you dont need `value` on a like, if it exists, it's a "like" and you should use is as a pivot table (you already have 2 foreign IDs in it)

```php
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->tinyInteger('is_dislike')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

then declare the relation between `Post` and `User`

**Post**

```php
public function votedUsers(){ //or simply likes
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'likes')->withPivot('is_dislike')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**User**

```php
public function votedPosts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'likes')->withPivot('is_dislike')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Next to create a like just do it like this

```php
public function liker($postId, $userId, $value){
    $user = User::findOrFail($userId); //or use auth()->user(); if it's the authenticated user
    $user->votedPosts()->attach($postId);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

to Remove a like use `detach($postId)` instead.

For dislike

```php
$user->votedPosts()->attach($postId, ['is_dislike' => 1]);
```

Comment: thank you for your time, btw I want the value for like or dislike('1' for like and '0' for dislike) so you think I should look for better ways to add dislikes?

Comment: in that case, yeah you need a field. Updated my answer. You will notice that in this structure, you can't like twice the same post and you cant "like" and "dislike" a post in the same time.